# SQL Group By and Calculation

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I am trying to create some queries in DBeaver. I have some questions regarding aggregation by using group by. I will use an example output table to explain (THIS IS THE OUTPUT by running my query):

```
ID SubType Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 Data 4
Sample 1 A Null Null 21 22
Sample 1 B 20 15 Null Null
```

So in here, I have used where statement to select sample 1, then based on group by subtype, I can retrieve different information from Sample 1 (based on subtype, some data will be Null as shown from the table due to the reason that some data is only available for either A or B).

Now the first difficulty for me: I want to create a new column "Data 5" for part B and the formula will be using 20 from Data 1 column, 15 Data 2 column and 21 from Data 3 column - i.e. 20/(21-15). Is this possible to make new output based on output results? Hope I don't confuse you here.

Second difficulty for me: Initially, I want to make a one row table for Sample 1. So basically, I don't want to group by subtype and just show Data 1 - Data 4 columns. However, my query has case and end as statements that search for keywords in Subtype column to retrieve info. Therefore, it forces me to use group by subtype (I guess??). I don't know what to do. Is there a way to make this simple? I want to make something like this:

```
ID Data 1 Data 2 Data 3 Data 4
Sample 1 20 15 21 22
```

If my questions are confusing, I can paste my actual query in here and output results so you guys can better understand.

Thank you for your help!!!!

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to see your queries

Comment: Please post your sample data. I suspect you are looking for CTEs (Common Table Expressions).

Comment: @OldProgrammer The query is attached as an image

Comment: @cddt The query is attached as an image

Comment: As you guys can see, I want to fix the syntax for Avg_cluster_spacing, which is wrong here (it doesn't allow me to write the correct syntax).  According to output, Avg_cluster_spacing should equal to 251.82/(63/10)=39.97. This is the value I want instead of 25.182.  The formula for Avg_cluster_spacing should be avg_stage_spacing/(perf_count/stage_count). However, I don't know how to write the syntax since SQL will say they don't exist. I can't merge everything into one row due to grow by limited by completion_type.

Comment: I assume it is quite difficult here because SQL is taking data from 2 different completion type for the same UWI to calculate my desired values (do i need a nested select statement or something?). In short, I need a syntax to do the following: when completion_type = "FRAC", calculate A and B; when completion_type="JETPERF", calculate C; then calculate A/(C/B) and save as Avg_Cluster_Spacing as a new column.

Comment: Please see my answer for an example with CTEs. 
PS in future please paste your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the summaries for `completion_type = 'FRAC'` and for `completion_type = 'JETPERF'` in separate CTEs. Then combine them as follows:

```
;WITH frac as (
SELECT
 c.uwi,
 AVG(c.base_depth - c.top_depth) AS Avg_stage_Spacing,
 COUNT(c.completion_type) AS Stage_Count
FROM
 well_completion AS c
WHERE
 c.completion_type = 'FRAC'
GROUP BY
 c.uwi
), 
jetperf as (
SELECT
 c.uwi,
 COUNT(c.completion_type) AS Perf_Count
FROM
 well_completion AS c
WHERE
 c.completion_type = 'JETPERF'
GROUP BY
 c.uwi
)
SELECT
 f.uwi,
 f.Avg_stage_Spacing / (j.Perf_count / f.Stage_Count) AS Avg_cluster_spacing
FROM
 frac as f
  INNER JOIN
 jetperf as j
  ON
   f.uwi = j.uwi
```

Comment: @GoldenSun if I have answered your question, please accept it as the correct answer. If it does not answer your question, please provide more information.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as the correct answer. Is there anything else i need to do? Please teach me.

Comment: @GoldenSun Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you take the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). After that, you could read some useful pages in the [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help), such as [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select id, max(data1) as data1,max(data2) as data2,max(data3) as data3,max(data4) as data4
from tablename
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks. Please also see my attached query!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
select id, max(data1) as data1,max(data2) as data2,max(data3) as data3,max(data4) as data4
from tablename group by SubType
```

Comment: Thanks. Please also see my attached query!